# One of my website's navbar button is not jumping to the correct section of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor-scroll

This is my HTML for my Navbar buttons

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#Home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Portfolio" class="smoothScroll">Portfolio</a </li>
                <li><a href="#Contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>

            </div>
```

So when I click the portfolio button, it should jump to the portfolio section: this one

```
                <a name="Portfolio">
            <!-- <section id="Portfolio"> -->
            <div id="whitecontainer1">
                <h1> Portfolio </h1>
                hello
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

            </div>
            </a>
```

But instead it jumps/scrolls to this section

```
<section id="About">
            <div id="redcontainer1">
                <div id="aboutinfo">
                    <h2><strong>Ashpan Raskar</strong></h2>
                    <div id="aboutme">
                        I am an intuitive <strong> software developer</strong>, and newly a
<strong> web developer</strong>. I began by learning Java at the age of 10 from an online
YouTube series: "Java (Beginner) Programming Tutorials." Soon after I started becoming
interested in <strong>Websites 
and Web Design</strong>, so I learned how to create websites with XHTML, but it was not at 
all responsive and was bare to the bone.
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        From then a learned quite a few more languages such as Jquery,
PHP, Javascript, C#, Ajax, etc, and I plan to learn Android Development as my next stage.

                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <a target="_blank"class="btn btn-default" href="Ashpan_Raskar.pdf" role="button">Check out my Resume!</a>
                    </div>
```

Any help is really appreciated, my code is on GitHub, you can see it here https://github.com/Ashpanr/Personal-Website-v1/
Thanks in advance

Comment: Cant see any element with `id="Portfolio"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in Lines `80 - 81` of `index.html`:

```
<a name="Portfolio">
<!-- <section id="Portfolio"> -->
```

Change it to:

```
<section id="Portfolio">
```

And it works well. The reason behind it is, `<a>` you have given and there's no closing tag. There's a `</section>` at line `93` but no starting tag. And moreover, it is better to use `<element id="section-name">` than giving the **deprecated** `<a name="section-name">`. A major reason is, you cannot have `block` elements inside `inline` `<a>` element. It is that, simply, you cannot have `<div>` or any other block level tags inside `<a>` tag.

**But the real reason is...**

You have the following CSS:

```css
#introbg {position: absolute;}
```

And this doesn't tell the browser, where it finishes. You should not use `position: absolute` without a reason. And so, the `<a name="Portfolio">`, which comes later gets the position before `#intro`.

Remove the `position: absolute` for the code and it will work correctly.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much... But there is a problem now, how do I move an image without have the "position: (absolute or relative). Im trying it but it doesnt move anywhere without that.

Comment: How do you wanna move them?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. It was in the CSS of the Bootstrap Stylesheet. Thanks so much, this really helped me out! :)